# VBA change cell to become double-click

Tags: vba, excel

In a sheet I have in my workbook, there are cells in in the F column that turn red and when they're clicked once, it will pull up a sheet of values. I would like to change that to become, once cells in the F column are double-clicked, **then** will it pull up a sheet of values. This sheet is called "JE" and here is the code I have for it:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MySheet As String
    On Error GoTo Done:
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MySheet = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Offset(0, -2).Value, Sheets("ref_list").Range("$C$1:$D$17"), 2, 0)
        Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Sheets(MySheet).Activate
    End If

Done:
Sheets("acct_codes").Visible = 0


End Sub
```

I believe I should make this sub to a "before double click" but I'm unsure if I can keep the code as is. Not totally sure how to complete this.

Comment: Just make sure you add `cancel=true` so that someone will not go into an in-cell edit on the double-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim MySheet As String
        On Error GoTo Done:
        If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Cancel = True
            MySheet = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Offset(0, -2).Value, Sheets("ref_list").Range("$C$1:$D$17"), 2, 0)
            Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
            Sheets(MySheet).Activate
        End If

Done:
    Sheets("acct_codes").Visible = 0
End Sub
```